# How not to accept numbers in TextBox?

Tags: vb.net

I know how to do the above opposite. Have it only accept numbers, but how about for it to accept everything other then `0123456789`?

Code I use for numbers only.

```
If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then

            If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
                My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk)
                e.Handled = True

            End If

        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Char.IsDigit to tell if a character is a decimal digit.

```
If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
    My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk)
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one.

```
If Not Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) And Not e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Delete) And Not e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Back) Then    
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Just invert the condition?

```
If Not (Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57) Then
```